# How to add md-switch to angular 4

Tags: angular

i want to add md-switch from [AngularJS Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/switch) to my angular4 project, but i'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'md-switch' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-switch' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-switch' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message
```

===============================

## UPDATE

test.component.html:

```
<md-slide-toggle>Slide me!</md-slide-toggle>
```

test.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
```

test.module.ts

```
import { MaterialModule, MdButtonModule, MdSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MaterialModule, MdSlideToggleModule,
  ],
})
export class TestModule { }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "web-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

What am i missing?

Comment: please remove 'angularjs' tag since that is for angular 1x projects.

Comment: hey thanks to your comment, now i'm clearer about the difference surrounding the terms angularJs, angular, angular2, angular4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the angular1 lib docs for an angular2 module...

If you already have [this](https://github.com/angular/material2) repo installed just import the desired functionality from material to your module, else install package:

```
npm install @angular/material
```

Don´t forget to include the feature component module on your selected module:

test.module.ts:

```
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';

    imports:      [ MatSlideToggleModule,
```

test.component.html:

```
<mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>
```

test.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
})
export class testComponent{}
```

Comment: hi i installed @angular/material, added import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular/material';, @NgModule ({
  imports: [MdButtonModule],
}), replace with <md-button > in .html but im still getting the same error

Comment: in both import cases on your module doc you should add both MaterialModule and MdButtonModule ... saying just in case

Comment: in my package.json, its using "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.7"... is this correct?

Comment: Should be, I am currently on 2.0.0-beta.3 and the components work just fine with above config.... trying to think what could be wrong with your case...

Comment: i updated my code above and included the package.json

Comment: hey it works. im rather new to angular, so i created a test.module.ts and it didnt work. instead i placed my codes into the app.module.ts and it works

Comment: Is this still current?  Not ablet to import these modules (IDE doesn't recognize them) even though I've installed @angular/material

Comment: let me update, recently material replaced md with mat in all modules

Comment: if you are using latest versions it should work with those edits

Answer (score 1):

First of all angularjs material is not compatible with angular 4  instead use angular material 2. And before adding angular material ,Check this issue:

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4137

Treeshaking is not happening in angular material. Even if you use one module it will import everything and it will increase your build size, hence decrease the performance. So, I would recommend to either use any other library or write your own custom css.

Some of the material libraires that you can use are:

- [Prime NG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/)
- [Md2](http://code.promactinfo.com/md2/) by promact